# Receiving Javascript NaN When calculating input fields

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using Jquery to calculate the totals of the inputs for this carpet calculator I'm writing. The problem I'm experiencing is being able to output the values while I'm in the for loop but getting NaN when I am outside of both loops as seen below.

Here's a working example of the problem I'm experiencing as well -

https://codepen.io/CodeHero1/pen/abdjpgL

```
    $('#calculate-cost').on('click',function(){


    var widthTotalFeet = $('.room-width-feet').map((_,el) => el.value).get();
    var widthTotalInches = $('.room-width-inches').map((_,el) => el.value).get();

    var roomWidthTotalFeet = 0;  // total feet
    var roomWidthTotalInches = 0;  // total inches


    for(var i = 0; i < widthTotalFeet.length; i++) {

        roomWidthTotalFeet += parseInt(widthTotalFeet[i]);
        console.log('in array');
        //This increments correctly
        console.log('feet +' + roomWidthTotalFeet);
    }


    for(var i = 0; i < widthTotalInches.length; i++) {

        roomWidthTotalInches += parseInt(widthTotalInches[i]);
        //This increments correctly
        console.log('inches +' + roomWidthTotalInches);

    }

    var roomFeetAndInches = parseFloat(roomWidthTotalFeet + '.' + roomWidthTotalInches);

    

        //Receiving NaN on these console logs
        console.log('Parse ' + roomFeetAndInches);
        console.log('room widht feet=' + roomWidthTotalFeet);
        console.log('room widht inches=' + roomWidthTotalInches);


});
```

Comment: Your "working example" does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with your usage of `parseInt`. The `widthTotalFeet` and `widthTotalInches` arrays can possibly look something like this: `['1','', '2']` ... where `empty string` is in place for any empty fields. If you do `parseInt('')` it will result in `NaN`. To fix this you should exclude the empty strings or make sure they add `0` in your loops.

Comment: Good catch! I added 0 in my loops and that worked great. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure `roomWidthTotalFeet` and `roomWidthTotalInches` doesn't have trailing spaces? Try making the float conversion like this:

```
var roomFeetAndInches = parseFloat(trim(roomWidthTotalFeet) + "." + trim(roomWidthTotalInches));
```

Moreover, it's better to use double quotes in place of single ones...

Comment: I'm no expert on imperial units, but I'm fairly sure you can't just mash the numbers together. 5ft10in for example would not be `5.10` feet.

Comment: It's true @Niet the Dark Absol. At first let's try the float conversion to work. After that we can fix the bugs. Who knows if Joe Z need to represent the result like that...

Comment: If your answer is just one step in fixing the problem, you need to make that *very* clear and likely post as a comment rather than a "finished solution" answer.

Comment: Thanks for responding to my question. The trim is probably useful but the answer by @redouglas worked. As far as "mashing" these together, wouldn't passing this string into parseFloat() work?